# header by clicking button in JavaScript alert popup

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way to direct to a desired page by clicking the OK button in a JavaScript pop-up?

I am able to achieve it when not within php but when echoed im not sure.

```
else {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Wrong Username or Password")';
echo '</script>';
header("Location:login.php");
}
```

This headers OK but i would like it only to happen when the user clicks OK in the popup. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use pure javascript and the onclick event?

Comment: why use an alert at all? post to the login page and if something was wrong, let them know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
else {
?>
<script language="javascript">
    alert("Wrong Username or Password");
    location.href = "login.php";
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use javascript to do this:

```
else {
var popup = window.confirm("Wrong Username or Password");

if (popup==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  window.location.href = "yourdomain.com/login.php";
  }
else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't even need the confirm. Just run the window.location after the alert. The alert will steal the window until ok is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Wrong Username or Password")';
    echo 'window.location = "/login.php";'
    echo '</script>';
}
```

should work just fine. It won't redirect until OK is pressed.